# is JWT access token/refresh token flow ONLY the backend/server side bad?

Tags: security, session, jwt

Is refreshing JWT access token ONLY on the backend/server side bad?

I've read everywhere to use separate `/refresh` endpoint to obtain new access token when first request returns 401/403 error, but let's say both resource server and authentication server are just basic monolith app, and we can obtain new access token on the same backend.

Refresh endpoint called on the client side:
[image]

vs. obtaining new access token on the server side/backend only:
[image]

I've seen this sort of answer:

> If however your application is one big monolith, where every endpoint is hosted by the same server and therefore is capable of checking refresh tokens and issuing access tokens, then there is absolutely no reason for you to be using access tokens or JWTs in general. You should just use refresh tokens, which, in this case, would be better called a session token.

There is still a reason to use JWT just to reduce e.g. database calls needed to check validity of refresh token.

So why is it mostly done on the client side and is there anything wrong with doing it ONLY on the backend side.